# How to know which button is pressed ? Python Tkinter + SQLite

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, tkinter

I'm trying to develop a GUI application which manage tickets from SAV. I'm using Python Tkinter, sqlite3. 
My problem is that I create buttons for each tickets I have. This button is used to open the ticket's profil. But I don't know how to identify which button is pressed. Also every buttons has the same command, but datas displayed will be affect by this button.

I tried to create an ID for each case to identify the line but I didn't success this way

```py
for N_Nom in curseur.execute("SELECT Nom FROM client"):
    Label(FrameMain, text=N_Nom,bg='#C2C2C2',font=('Arial',12,'bold')).grid(row=c_nom.get(), column=1)
    c_nom.set(c_nom.get() + 1)

for N_Code in curseur.execute("SELECT Codification FROM SAV"):
    Label(FrameMain, text=N_Code,bg='#C2C2C2',font=('Arial',12,'bold')).grid(row=c_code.get(), column=2)
    c_code.set(c_code.get() + 1)

for N_State in curseur.execute("SELECT Etat_Ticket FROM SAV"):
    Label(FrameMain, text=N_State,bg='#C2C2C2',font=('Arial',12,'bold')).grid(row=c_state.get(), column=3)
    c_state.set(c_state.get() + 1)

for N_Date in curseur.execute("SELECT Date_Ticket FROM SAV"):
    Label(FrameMain, text=N_Date,bg='#C2C2C2',font=('Arial',12,'bold')).grid(row=c_date.get(), column=4)
    c_date.set(c_date.get() + 1)

for N_client in curseur.execute("SELECT Num_Ticket FROM SAV"):
    Label(FrameMain, text=N_client,bg='#C2C2C2',font=('Arial',12,'bold')).grid(row=c_client.get(), column=0)
    Button(FrameMain, text='Compléter', font=('Arial',14), cursor='hand2', command= lambda : config(N_client, N_Nom, N_Code, N_State, N_Date)).grid(row=c_client.get(),column=6, sticky='e')

    Label(FrameMain, text=N_client,bg='#C2C2C2',font=('Arial',12,'bold')).grid(row=c_client.get(), column=0)
    c_client.set(c_client.get() + 1)
```

So if you know how to solve this one, or if you can tell me if I can do it better. Thanks you

Comment: If u bind any function in a for loop, you might have to use `partial` ( `from functools import partial`) or if you don't want to use partial then try `lambda N_client=N_client: config(N_client, N_Nom, N_Code, N_State, N_Date)`. Also I don't even know what `config()` is from.

Comment: Thanks you, I'll try using partial. But for config(), I open another window where I display all datas corresponding to the button click, there is nothing very interesting to solve this issue.